# when I run my flutter application it comes up with a problem stating my dart sdk is below a sufficient version

Tags: flutter, macos, visual-studio-code, dart

I am making a flutter application on MAC but when I run it it returns an error saying my dart sdk is below the sufficient threshold to run my packages. I have now upgrading to the latest version of the dart sdk but it is still returning the same problem and I am unsure of how to change the dart sdk path or get it connected to the latest version in my terminal.

Comment: have you check your environment variables or what SDK that u use when you running the program? (in case you put the wrong dart path)

Answer (score 0):

I think you dart SDk version is older try upgrade or reinstall and then try flutter clean and pub get commands Hopefully it'll help

Comment: I had already updated it all that has done is give my app lots of problems the problem is my vscode not using the most up to date version of dart I have installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).